# Kotlin Cyclic Generics

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I have 3 classes Router, Interactor and Component and in java I have

```
Interactor<R extends Router>
Router<C extends InteractorComponent, I extends Interactor>
Component<I extends Interactor>
```

When I convert to Kotlin I get

```
Interactor<Self : Interactor<Self, R>, R> :
LifecycleScopeProvider<InteractorEvent> where R : Router<R, *, Self>

Router<Self : Router<Self, C, I>, in C, I>(
component: C,
private val interactor: I) where C : Component<I>, I : Interactor<I, Self>

Component<I : Interactor<I, *>>
```

However further down with some subclasses Router -> ViewRouter (which just adds a view) -> PagerViewRouter I run into this

```
PagerViewRouter<V, C, I>(
view: V,
component: C,
interactor: I) : ViewRouter<PagerViewRouter<V, C, I>, V, C, I>(
view,
component,
interactor) where V : View, C : Component<I>, I : ViewInteractor<I, PagerViewRouter<V, C, I>, *>
```

When I try to declare a list of these PagerViewRouters, which can each be different concrete types, I get the error that the ViewInteractor type is not within bounds

```
MutableList<PagerViewRouter<
        out View,
        out InteractorComponent<out ViewInteractor<*, *, *>>,
        out ViewInteractor<*, *, *>>>
```

Updating to the error basically causes infinite updates since ViewInteractor, like Interactor, references Self as the first generic

How can I reduce this complexity and avoid the cyclic references while still maintaining the type safety?

Comment: What you have in Java isn't type-safe, FWIW.

Comment: How could I make it type safe in Java? Maybe that would fix the kotlin issue